# web application hosting Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, frameworks, windows-server-2003

I hosted a web application on `Windows 7` and now I want it to be hosted on `Windows Server 2003`.

I am getting this error.

I copied the application to the server and added a new virtual directory pointing to it.

When I want to browse the application from the IIS this error rises:

```
Configuration Error:

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'type'.

Source Error: 

    <configuration>
       <configSections>
           <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" 
                         type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, 
                         Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

Is there any solution to solve the error or is there any other way to make the transition from `Windows 7` to `Windows Server 2003`?

Comment: What is the .NET framework this site is using?

Comment: .net 4.0 @AmiramKorach i also installed .net 4.0 on the server it also didn't work

Comment: Make sure you set the site to work in .NET 4 in iis. Open the site configuration. In asp.net tab make sure version 4 is selected.

Answer (score 1):

After you install .NET Framework 4.0, make sure its status is set to Allowed in the Web Service Extensions within IIS.

[image: IIS Web Service Extensions]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this is happening because your server doesn't have the .net framework installed as you have target in your own computer.

2 days ago I have same problem. in mine case I have update the web.config where server doesn't have new version of .net.

in your case you need to install new version of .net to server 2003.